# Find all positive integers $m$ and $n$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^m{k!}=n^2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all positive integers $m$ and $n$ such that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^m{k!}=n^2.$$
The only pair I have got so far is $(m,n)=(3,3)$.

I noticed that $n$ is odd and is a multiple of $3$, and I tried $\bmod 4,\bmod 8, \bmod 9$ but nothing happened. Actually I want to conjecture that $\exists m_0$ such that there will be no square values for LHS after this, but I don't know how to prove this.

Are there any methods to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Note that $\sum_{k=1}^ m k!$ is divisible by $3$ for all   $m\ge3.$

Comment: Have you tried working mod $5$?

Comment: I didn't. I will try it now. Thank you!

Comment: With trying mod 5, I found out that LHS cannot be a square whenever $m\geqslant 4$, so the solution I got is actually unique. Is that correct?

Comment: $(m,n)=(1,1)$ also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noted, if $m\ge4$ the sum is $3$ more than a multiple of $5$. You're right, that can't be square: the only allowed residues are $0,\,1$.