# Solve in natural

Tags: integers, natural-numbers

> $1!+2!+3!...x!=y^2$ Solve over the $N$
>
> I see (1;1), (3;3)
>
> $x^5+y^5+z^5=2009$ 
>   prove that there are no solutions in $Z$

Comment: $(1.)$ Part is a duplicate of [This.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3456915/find-all-positive-integers-m-and-n-such-that-sum-k-1mk-n2)

Comment: Also , Please read this [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to begin with and share your thoughts and efforts in the question

Comment: 1) Yeah thanks, in second one here you need to 
prove that there are no solutions

Comment: Hint for the second part:  work $\pmod {11}$.  That's a natural choice since $5\,|(11-1)$.

Comment: @lulu thanks!, question closed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Working in $\mod 11$ , we get $2009 \equiv 7 \mod 11$ . Now let us look at the possible remainders of $x^5$ in $\mod 11$.

$$\begin{align}  n &\quad 0 \,\,\,\,1\,\,\,\,2\,\,\,3\,\,\,\,4\,\,\,\,5\,\,\,\,6\,\,\,\,7\,\,\,\,8\,\,\,\,9\,\,\,\,10 \\
n^5 & \color{#4d4}{\quad 0 \,\,\,1\,\,\,10\,\,1\,\,\,\,1\,\,\,\,1\,\,10\,\,10\,\,10\,\,1 \,\,\,10}\end{align}$$

It is easy to conclude that there is no possible way to achieve $7$ as the remainder.

Hence there is no solution for the given equation.